# How can I store two values associated with an image in an array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to figure out a way I can store and associate a letter (a-z), a value (1-10), and an image with each other. For example, lets say that associate:

```
A with 2 with letterA.png
B with 1 with letterB.png
```

..etc

I'm thinking that I need some kind of array. It would be nice if I could use the letters as the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a dictionary of dictionaries? Your question is a bit vague to provide a perfect example, but something like this:

```
associationDictionary = {
    "A" = {
        "number" = 2;
        "image" = "letterA.png";
    }
    "B" = {
        "number" = 1;
        "image" = "letterB.png";
    }
}
```